# How to plot a seaborn boxplot for each month and year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seaborn

I have a time series data frame of precipitation values

```
print(rain_df)
```

```
          date  precip
0   2017-01-10     0.0
1   2017-01-17     1.0
2   2017-01-24     1.0
3   2017-01-31     4.0
4   2017-02-07     1.0
..         ...     ...
218 2021-04-27     1.7
219 2021-05-03    22.7
220 2021-05-10     0.0
221 2021-05-17     2.0
222 2021-05-25     0.2
```

```
rain_df = rain_df.join(model_data['date'].dt.month.astype(str).str.get_dummies())
rain_df = rain_df.join(rain_df['date'].dt.year.astype(str).str.get_dummies())
rain_df = rain_df[rain_df['precip']>0]
rain_df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)

print(rain_df)
```

```
          date  precip  1  10  11  12  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  2017  2018  \
0   2017-01-17     1.0  1   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     1     0   
1   2017-01-24     1.0  1   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     1     0   
2   2017-01-31     4.0  1   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     1     0   
3   2017-02-07     1.0  0   0   0   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     1     0   
4   2017-02-14    22.9  0   0   0   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     1     0   
..         ...     ... ..  ..  ..  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..   ...   ...   
175 2021-03-31    18.3  0   0   0   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0     0     0   
176 2021-04-27     1.7  0   0   0   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0     0     0   
177 2021-05-03    22.7  0   0   0   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0     0     0   
178 2021-05-17     2.0  0   0   0   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0     0     0   
179 2021-05-25     0.2  0   0   0   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0     0     0   

     2019  2020  2021  
0       0     0     0  
1       0     0     0  
2       0     0     0  
3       0     0     0  
4       0     0     0  
..    ...   ...   ...  
175     0     0     1  
176     0     0     1  
177     0     0     1  
178     0     0     1  
179     0     0     1
```

How can I create a boxplot where the x-axis is the month-year and y-axis is the precip value?

This was my attempt

```
# reverse one-hot encoding
rain_df['month-year'] = (rain_df.iloc[:, 2:] == 1).idxmax(1)

rain_df = rain_df.melt(id_vars='month-year',value_vars='precip', value_name='precip')

print(rain_df)
```

```
    month-year variable  precip
0            1   precip     1.0
1            1   precip     1.0
2            1   precip     4.0
3            2   precip     1.0
4            2   precip    22.9
..         ...      ...     ...
175          3   precip    18.3
176          4   precip     1.7
177          5   precip    22.7
178          5   precip     2.0
179          5   precip     0.2
```

```
ax=sn.boxplot(x='month-year', y='precip', hue='variable', data=rain_df, palette="Set3", linewidth=1)
ax.set_title('Joliette')
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

The problem here is that it only plots the months in the x-axis with no information on the given year. Did I mess up with my `melt` function or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, but I've not been able to test it myself. I am a bit unsure of the column type of `date`. `melt` wont be necessary.

```py
rain_df['month_year'] = rain_df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b %Y')) # e.g. Jul 2021

rain_df = rain_df[rain_df['precip'] > 0][['month_year', 'precip']] # df now consists of these two rows

ax = sn.boxplot(x='month_year', y='precip', data=rain_df, palette="Set3", linewidth=1)

ax.set_title('Joliette')
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 3):

- I think the easiest solution is to use [`seaborn.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) and just pass the appropriate `.dt` component to `x` and `hue`
- The `'date'` in the test `df` below is a `datetime dtype`.

  - Convert the real `'date'` to a `datetime dtype` with `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)`

### Imports and Test DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from calendar import month_abbr as months  # optional
import numpy as np  # for test data

# test dataframe
np.random.seed(365)
rows = 250

dates = pd.bdate_range('2017-01-01', '2021-07-21', freq='D')
data = {'date': np.random.choice(dates, size=(rows)),
        'precip': np.random.randint(0, 31, size=(rows))}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head())
        date  precip
0 2017-01-10     0.0
1 2017-01-17     1.0
2 2017-01-24     1.0
3 2017-01-31     4.0
4 2017-02-07     1.0
```

### Plot with months on x-axis

```py
# get month names; optional step for renaming the xticklabels
months = list(months)[1:]

# now just plot the dateframe with seaborn
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))

sns.boxplot(x=df.date.dt.month, y=df.precip, hue=df.date.dt.year, ax=ax)
ax.legend(title='Year', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
ax.set(xlabel='Month', xticklabels=months)  # setting the xticklabels is optional
plt.show
```

[image]

### Plot with years on the x-axis

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 7))

sns.boxplot(x=df.date.dt.year, y=df.precip, hue=df.date.dt.month, ax=ax)
ax.legend(title='Month', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
ax.set(xlabel='Year')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create your months using `dt.strftime`. Eg:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['1918-11-11'])).dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
0    Nov-1918
dtype: object
```

Do this on your `rain_df['date']` column and assign to `month-year`. If that doesn't work, your data might not be in a `datetime64` format. Fix by calling `pd.to_datetime` on it before invoking `.dt.strftime`. With your new `month-year` column, plot again.